# For loop should iterate only after subscribe method's body executed (nested subscribe in forloop) in angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a nested subscribe in a for each loop where the inner subscribe takes the result of the outer subscribe as input. I need the code to be like when it is iterating inside the for loop, it should call the outer subscribe and the result/output of it to be passed to inner subscribe. Here for loop should wait until the process is completed before moving to the next iteration. Here I'm providing a demo for this

```
this.forVar.forEach(item =>{
   this.service.outerSubscribe(item).subscribe(res=>{
      //some coding here 
      this.service.innerSubscribe(res).subscribe(res1=>{//some coding here});
   });
//for each should iterate only after both subscribes are executed.  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the function `combineLatest` and a `higher-order mapping operator` like `switchMap`.

```js
// use switchMap to get values from the inner subscription
const createNestedSubscriptionFromItem = item => 
  this.service.outerSubscribe(item).pipe(
    switchMap(res => this.service.innerSubscribe(res))
  );

// create an array of subscriptions
const subscriptions = this.forVar.map(item => 
  createNestedSubscriptionFromItem(item)
);

// use combineLatest to get updates from all results.
// here you can use other functions like merge or jorkJoin instead combineLatest. 
const allResults$ = combineLatest(subscriptions);
```

See more info about static functions and operators in the official [API Reference](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api);